# Double genitive

Tags: grammaticality, double-possessive

Which of the following is grammatical?

> 1. That action would not increase my satisfaction, but the one of my driver's.
> 2. That action would not increase my satisfaction but my driver's one

I think 1) is correct, whilst 2) is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: I think the fundamental grammatical problem here is that you can't use "one" for mass nouns.

Comment: It is not clear whether you mean your driver's satisfaction or your driver's action.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The double genitive certainly exists in English and often takes the form *a friend of my brother’s*. However, neither of the examples you give is likely to be produced by a native speaker. A clearer way of putting it would be *That action would not increase my satisfaction but it would increase my driver's*. Even that sounds a little strange. More probable, depending on the circumstances, would be something like *Doing that doesn’t make me any happier, but my driver seems to like it.*

Answer (score 9):

The problem with both statements is the inclusion of "the one".

Possible alternatives:

Quite formal sounding but acceptable ...

- "That action would not increase my satisfaction, but that of my driver."

More relaxed but keeping your original structure ...

- "That action would increase my driver's satisfaction but not mine"

Conversational but (hopefully) staying true to your original intent ...

- "That would satisfy my driver but not me."

Answer (score 5):

Neither sounds right to me.  I think it would be better stated this way:

> That action would not increase my satisfaction, but that of my driver.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that both these sentences are written poorly.  The word "one" cannot be used of an abstract noun such as "satisfaction".  I think that "that" would be better.  A change in word order would remove the ambiguity of the second sentence: "That action would increase not my satisfaction but my driver's".  In fact, in these cases, there is no need for a pronoun, as "satisfaction" is easily implied in the second clause.  The alternatives presented by *ljj101* are all better than both original sentences, although the first is not great.